# Does not implement methodSignatureForSelector and unrecognized selector when using Timer

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

Here I have a simple class that prints "test" several times a second:

```
import Foundation

class TestClass {

    static var count = 0
    static var timer = Timer()

    init() {
        TestClass.start()
    }

    static func start() {
        TestClass.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0/5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(printTest), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func printTest() {
        print(count)
        count += 1
    }
}
```

I made the function `start` the variable `timer` `static` so that later on I can start and stop the timer from another class

In my main ViewController file, I simply make a new `TestClass` by saying:

```
let _ = TestClass()
```

Then I try to stop and start the timer by doing:

```
if /*something*/ {
    TestClass.timer.invalidate()
}

if /*something else*/ {
    TestClass.start()
}
```

However when I run the project, I get multiple errors in the console:

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x10eaab580 of class 'DeleteMe.TestClass' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
```

and

```
Unrecognized selector +[DeleteMe.TestClass printTest]
```

Is there something I have to modify in the class to resolve the errors?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `start` is a `static` method so `self` is the class, not an instance. This means that `printTest` also needs to be `static`.

But why are these static? Why create an instance just to call the static `start` method?

Get rid of `init` and simply use `TestClass.start()`.

Or make everything a proper instance property and instance method. Then you can create separate instances of `TestClass` each their own timer.